# How can I block all ports except 443 on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, network, catalina, firewall

I realize this will break a lot of built in functionality on macOS as it ships, but for test reasons I want to temporarily block all tcp inbound / outbound ports on macOS Catalina except 443.

How can I do this in a way that's somewhat easy to toggle on/off once it's set up?

Comment: Since OS X Lion, `pfctl` is used to set traditional firewall preferences. This is still the case as of Catalina. [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474165/301961) for how to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple's application firewall is designed to have many exceptions to work with its services so the system prefs will take a lot of clicks. I will suggest a more command-line way to accomplish this large change in port access for the built-in pf firewall (no need for extra software).

Here is a simple rule set that will block all traffic except for ports 80 and 443 (http and https).  I don't advise saving it in your `/etc/pf.conf` in case things go sideways - a simple reboot (if you have `pf` set to load at boot) will fix things.  I used the filename `~/pf_rules01.conf`, you can call it what you like.

#### Create the rule file

```
# Set the interface to be used
if="en0"

# Default Deny Policy
block all

# Skip the loop back interface
set skip on lo

# Set http(80) & https (443) ports #
web_ports = "{80 443}"

# Pass in only web traffic
pass in quick on $if proto tcp to any port $web_ports keep state
pass out quick on $if proto tcp to any port $web_ports keep state
```

#### Test the file

Before you enable the new rule set (keep in mind that you **specifically** asked for all protocols to be blocked except 443), you can check for syntax errors with the command:

```
$ sudo pfctl -n -f /path/to/rulefile
```

- The `-n` tells `pfctl` to just parse the rules
- The `-f` specifies what file to load; the default is `/etc/pf.conf`

#### Enable `pf`

If all is good, enable the rule set with the `-e` flag

```
$ sudo pfctl -e -f /path/to/rulefile
```

#### Testing...

From another machine, issue the command `telnet <machinename || IPaddress> 80` of the host running your web server.  If everything works, you'll receive something similar to the following:

```
Trying 192.168.1.123...
Connected to testmachine.home.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Success!  You can also try pointing your browser to the address and if you get a response from the server, it works.

#### Caveats

1. ***This blocks all traffic*** with the exception of 80 and 443 (http and https).  If you are SSHing into this box, you *will* lose your connection because it's not passing SSH (port 22) in or out (maybe pass 22 as well?).
2. `en0` is *my* network adapter (wired).  Yours may be different.  To get a listing of your network interfaces, use the `ifconfig` command.  They are usually at the top of the output starting with `en0`, `en1` etc.
3. This was tested on a FreeBSD server running [`dhttpd`](https://www.freshports.org/www/dhttpd/) (not Apache). You can't test unless you have *something* listening and responding on the ports you're interested in.

   I typically don't run any sort of web server on my Mac, but in VMs
   for the sake of portability, security, and stability.  However, `pf`
   is based on BSD and the rules and commands are identical.
4. If you want to turn this off just issue the command `sudo pfctl -d` and it will disable the `pf` firewall.

Comment: `keep state` is not needed, it's there by default

Comment: `set skip on lo` — loopback is `lo0` on BSDs.

Comment: @poige - The *interfaces* are different and I put it in my answer to be Apple specific.  BSD doesn’t have an interface called `en0`.

Comment: I'm not saying anything about `en0` but loopback instead which is `lo0` both in macOS and BSDs.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. One thing though, pf will report a syntax error if there is no newline at the end of your pf_rules01.conf file.