# How do I close a port on a Mac?

Tags: macos, network, security, firewall

I was wondering if someone could tell me how to close a TCP/UDP port on a Mac completely.

I don't want to kill a process or anything behind it. I want the port to be closed off completely.

Thanks,

PN

Comment: Which type of port? Like superglue something in the USB port? Also, you tagged this with package management and hardware so I’m sort of not sure what the results you seek look like.

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/380010/119271  It's almost a dupe except for the one port exception....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I block all ports except 443 on macOS Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380010/how-can-i-block-all-ports-except-443-on-macos-catalina)

Comment: Hi All, I'm not hugely technical. I'm just wondering if there is a way to open and block Apple OS ports from the command line. It only needs to be a temporary fix right now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To block ports, you have to use the firewall which is what's shown in the link provided.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a firewall, that is well documented how to turn it on and make exceptions to the default rules.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201642

In the advanced settings there is a “block all incoming connections” toggle for that specific simple configuration.